# How can I make a wordpress shortcode function reusable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a custom blog (No templates, minimal plugins). And I have this code snippet in my functions.php file to display blogs by that category (Day Trips). My problem is, I would like to make this a little more maintainable and less verbose by making the category name dynamic at the use-level. I have about 30 different categories. I would hate to make 30 copies of this shortcode and assign each to a category.

Here's my shortcode

```
        // Blog Posts Queries
    function day_trips_blogs() {
        ob_start();

        $the_query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'category_name' => 'day-trips', <-- THIS PART
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'orderby'=> 'date', 
                'order' => 'DESC' 
            ) 
        ); 
        
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
            ?>
                <div class="uk-grid postcards">
                <?php
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {     
                            $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post=""->ID), '335.95, 335.95' ); 
                            ?>   
                            <div class="uk-width-1-3@m uk-margin-bottom">
                                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-padding-remove">
                                    <div class="uk-card-header uk-padding-remove">
                                        <div class="uk-card-media-top">
                                            <a class="text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                                <div class="card-image lazy-load-active text-center" style="background-size:cover; background-image: url( '<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); "></div> 
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="uk-card-body uk-padding-small">
                                            <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center">
                                                <?php the_title() ?>
                                            </h3>

                                            <p class="uk-margin-bottom">
                                                By: <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
                                            </p>

                                            <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    } else { 
                        // if no featured image is found
                        ?> 
                            <div class="uk-width-1-3@m uk-margin-bottom">
                                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-padding-remove">
                                    <div class="uk-card-body uk-padding-small">
                                        <a class="text-dark" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                            <h3 class="uk-card-title">
                                                <?php the_title() ?>
                                            </h3>
                                        </a>
                                        <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>       
                        <?php
                    }
                }
        } else {   
                // if no data is found
            ?>
                <div class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries uk-grid friends">
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">
                        <h4>No blogs are available yet. Come back soon!</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
        }

        return ob_get_clean();

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    add_shortcode('day-trips-posts', 'day_trips_blogs');
```

How can I pass `'category_name' => '??????'` to the shortcode itself so I can call it like this

```
    [blogs category="day-trips"]
    [blogs category="recipes"]
    [blogs category="whatever"]
```

Comment: Have you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API?

Comment: I did, Everything you see in the question was from there. But this part still escapes me. Sorry. You can vote it down if you'd like

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232197/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-shortcode

Comment: So, I need to store it in a `$content` variable and return it? What about the `ob_get_clean()` return I already have there? And how does it know what category I am calling by just adding an attribute called name? I used it this way `
 $a = shortcode_atts(array('name' => 'category_name'  ),  $atts );` and it still gave me what was already hard-coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass attributes to shortcode:

```
function day_trips_blogs( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'my_category' => 'default-category',
    ), $atts, 'day-trips-posts' );

    ob_start();

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'category_name' => $atts['my_category']
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby'=> 'date', 
            'order' => 'DESC' 
        ) 
    );
```

Rest of the code could stay the same, but I would push query before ob_start, to keep only rendering inside buffer.

then you will call it:

[day-trips-posts my_category="foo"]

Comment: OOOHH I see, you have to declare the attribute and the assign it to the query. I couldn't put those two together. Thanks man